# Ownership and shared_ptr in dependent classes

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, ownership

In my program I am drawing a block of text to screen and I want to be able to find the text that corresponds to a given pixel. In my architecture there are two classes, the `text_view` and the `draw_device`. `draw_device` is an abstract base class which provides drawing functions as well as functions to calculate, in pixel terms, the size of a given block of text. `text_view` is a class that stores information about where blocks and lines of text are on screen in order to speed up lookup and redraw operations.

Since `text_view` stores pixel information, it is necessarily dependent on the choice of `draw_device`. If a different `draw_device` is used, it might render text somewhat differently and leave the `text_view` storage in inconsistent state.

My question is, how best to represent this relationship?

I can let the user of the two classes deal with it, and pass in a `draw_device` reference for each function called. They would need to always pass in the same type of `draw_device` or evil will happen.

```
class text_view{
public:
    void rearrange_text(const draw_device &);
    int lookup_text(const draw_device &, int x, int y) const;
    void draw_text(draw_device &) const;
};
```

I can keep a naked pointer in the `text_view` to the `draw_device` to simplify the function interfaces, at the cost of requiring the user of the classes deal with managing the lifetime issues

```
class text_view{
    draw_device * device;
public:
    void rearrange_text();
    int lookup_text(int x, int y) const;
    void draw_text() const;
    void change_draw_device(draw_device *);
};
```

I can keep a `shared_ptr` in the `text_view` so the user won't have to worry about lifetime issues, at the cost of forcing them to use a `shared_ptr` instead of stack allocating or a `unique_ptr` etc.

I don't like the `shared_ptr` solution as I don't think the `text_view` should own the `draw_device`. It is merely a user of it.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution or some information you could share?